# NodeJS Hello World script not running

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to run a simple Hello World app in node, thing is I'm using console.log to print to stdout instead of using a fancy http server or anything.

I am running NodeJS LTS, `node v6.10.0` `npm 4.3.0` on Windows 10 x64.

The script I'm running is basically just a `console.log("Hello World");`.

Now if I run this line from inside the node command line, it works just fine.

But if I try running putting it into a separate file and running it via `node program.js` where `program.js` is `console.log("Hello World");`

So, why I am getting this output:

```
D:\nodeschool\HelloWorld>node program.js
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\nodeschool\HelloWorld\program.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Oh and the file is definitely there:

```
     Directory of D:\nodeschool\HelloWorld

    01.03.2017.  18:14    <DIR>          .
    01.03.2017.  18:14    <DIR>          ..
    01.03.2017.  18:04    <DIR>          node_modules
    01.03.2017.  18:14               253 package.json
    01.03.2017.  17:34                27 program.js.txt
    2 File(s)            280 bytes
    3 Dir(s)  627.008.479.232 bytes free
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: That error usually means the path to `program.js` is incorrect. Are you sure that you have the correct path & file extension?

Comment: And maybe your node.js installation requires program.js to be executable: `chmod 755 program.js`

Comment: @StevenSchobert the only thing inside program.js is `console.log("Hello World");` I just installed NodeJS a few hours ago, and the file IS there.

@Psi, I'm kinda on windows, via a Administrator rights command prompt, so.. don't think so. It runs other node stuff, like the learnyounode package from nodeschool.io, so why it wouldn't run this is beyond me.

Comment: @EdisGolubich If you run `dir` from that `D:\nodeschool\HelloWorld` directory, what do you see?

Comment: @StevenSchobert I added the output above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of the `dir` command, your filename is actually `program.js.txt`.

So when you run `node program.js`, it can't find any file named `program.js`, which results in the error you see.

Rename your file to `program.js` (without the `.txt` extension) and try it again.

Comment: Nevermind, I was running it on a fresh Windows machine, the file extensions are hidden in Explorer so I kept editing program.js.txt while running program.js.

Typical, thanks, had to actually check out the folder in the command line ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can be either of two case: one your `program.js` is not in this path `D:\nodeschool\HelloWorld\program.js` or your node.js installation is not executable in that path. "Try checking `chmod` of `program.js`